# How do I use setuptools to create a python package with multiple modules?

Tags: python, setuptools

I want to organize a distribution with several modules. Eventually there will be a C extension module, and at the same 'level', several pure python modules. I am not sure whether the top level should just be considered a namespace.

For starters, I would like to create a module monty.spam. It will be a C extension. I lifted this out of the [Extending Python docs.](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html)

monty/spam/spammodule.c

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject * spam_system (PyObject * self, PyObject * args)
  {
  const char * command;
  int          sts;

  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple (args, "s", &command))
    return NULL;
  sts = system (command);
  return Py_BuildValue ("i", sts);
  }

static 
PyMethodDef SpamMethods [] = {
             { "system", spam_system, METH_VARARGS, "Execute a shell command" },
             { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL }    
             };

PyMODINIT_FUNC
initspam (void)
  {
  (void) Py_InitModule ("spam", SpamMethods);
  }
```

I created a setup tools setup.py in the same directory, ran "python setup.py develop" and the module worked fine.

monty/spam/setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension

module = Extension ('spam', sources = [ 'spammodule.c' ])

setup (
      name = 'MontyP',
      version = '0.2', 
      description = 'pure spam',
      ext_modules = [ module ]
      )
```

In the monty directory:

```
python -c 'import monty.spam'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named monty.spam
```

So now I would like to create a distribution in which spam "lives in" monty. I have tried a number of variations on the setup.py them in the monty directory. (Both directories have an empty `__init__.py`)

My latest try at monty/setup.py: (yes, the find_packages () has no utility in this version.)

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension, find_packages

module = Extension ('spam', sources = [ './spam/spammodule.c' ])

print find_packages ()
setup (
      name               = 'MontyP',
      version            = '0.2', 
      namespace_packages = [ 'monty' ],
      packages           = find_packages (),
      description        = 'pure spam',
      ext_modules        = [ module ]
      )
```

No Joy!

```
python setup.py develop
['spam']
error in MontyP setup command: Distribution contains no modules or packages for namespace package 'monty'
```

Comment: I fully understand that at the time you ask a question like this you don't know what is relevant information and what is not. I have had questions "put on hold" for this and it is a PITA. That said, I think all the C extension stuff is a red herring here and should be removed to make the namespace issue more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need two or three changes to make it work.

First, instead of placing it at `monty/spam`, `setup.py` should be placed in the same level as `monty/`:

[image]

`setup.py` always goes in the root of the project.

Also, create an `__init__.py` file in `monty` but **no `__init__.py` inside `spam`**.

Now, in `setup.py`, in the line "`module = Extension ('spam', sources = [ 'spammodule.c' ])`", replace `spam` by `monty.spam` and `spammodule.c` by `monty/spam/spammodule.c`:

```
module = Extension ('monty.spam', sources = [ 'monty/spam/spammodule.c' ])
```

This is necessary because external modules should be declared with their full names (`monty.spam` instead of `spam`). Also, since now `setup.py` is in the root of the project, it should receive a relative but complete path to the C source file.

That's it, your module should work now.